# Dynamic PDO AND and OR

Tags: pdo, yii

I have a problem with Yii's `CDBCrtieria` builder. I am trying to make a rather complex query while using the escaping and safe functions provided by PDO.

Here is the query I am basically trying to build:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_audit_log 
    WHERE (model_id = 1 AND model = "Title") OR 
          (model_id = 1 AND model = "Product") //etc
```

This is being built dynamically in PHP like:

```
$model_ids = array(array($model->id, 'Title'));
foreach($model->products as $id => $product){
    $model_ids[][] = $product->id;
    $model_ids[][] = "Product";
}
```

So I don't know the values of the `WHERE` before I build the query. I must find an easy way to build:

```
    WHERE (model_id = 1 AND model = "Title") OR 
          (model_id = 1 AND model = "Product") //etc
```

Dynamically.

I have looked through the documentation but the closest thing I see is `addCondition` which would require complex coding to get working properly.

Does Yii provide any easy way of achieving this without having to deal with writing complex code to name my params etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is indeed a bit more complex, but here's a working solution:

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$param_id = 0;
// $model_ids is the one you built in your original code
foreach( $model_ids as $id_pair ) {
    $criteria->addCondition( '( model_id = :id' . $param_id . ' AND model = :model' . $param_id . ' )', 'OR' );
    $criteria->params[ ':id' . $param_id ] = $id_pair[0];
    $criteria->params[ ':model' . $param_id ] = $id_pair[1];
    $param_id++;
}
```

This will generate custom identifiers for each of your parameters so they will all be validated. Then you can just use `$criteria` in your query.

Comment: Awesome Sauce I forgot you can do that! I'll test and mark as soon as I can thanks :)